# ArrayList<Integer> will only keep one set of parameters. the rest is not being updated

Tags: java

I'm confused as to why the variable answer will only output one set of answer. I have a recur function that basically counts from i to size. it will then return the arraylist of the counts. then increment i and repeat. but when I output to the console I get:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

[]

[]

[]

[]

I was expecting something like this:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

......

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> practice(ArrayList<Integer> x, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> y){
    
    int inputSize = x.size();
    ArrayList<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++){

        answer = recur(x, y, i);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }


 public static ArrayList<Integer> recur(ArrayList<Integer> x1, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> y1, int index){
    ArrayList<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    for(int i = index; i < x1.size(); i++){
          
        ans.add(i);  
    }
      
    return ans;
}
```

Do I have to deallocate answer memory after the println?

Comment: Can you show the code of your `recur` method? Going by your output it returns empty lists for everything but the first call, but without knowing what exactly the code is it is kind of hard for us to tell you why.

Comment: Without showing `recur` method how could we define where is the problem?

Comment: Yes: I would have the same expectations

Comment: Curious to know the value of `x`

Comment: Filling in (or fixing, like removing the unused return type of your practice method) things you left out of the code i tried reproducing your output but cannot reproduce it at all:  https://ideone.com/PIepCU  - Either there is something important in your code you omitted telling us or you aren't running the code posted above.

Comment: BTW, what is the point of the `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> y1` parameter? You never use it anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: `practice` is having return type , which is not seeing in posted code. You might need to share further details to help here. Also issue is not reproduceable if I use void return type for `practice` & just print values inside `practice`

Comment: you are right, I am not sharing the entire code. I do not want any trouble with plagiarism as it is for a school assignment. this is a very simple version of it. I thought it would be enough for you guys to figure out why answer only print one recur return. Sorry

Comment: See answer.  Don't need y.  Indices are not evolving as expected.  index = 7 which is the size of the input array so after the first run of `practice` `recur` will never iterate.

Comment: BTW, you have already deallocated the answer memory as soon as you terminated the recur method, just not explicitly.  The only way it wouldn't deallocate is if recur somehow ran forever, because the reference to `answer` is by-value.  This is true for `ArrayList` and `Array`.

Java does this for you using Garbage Collection.  All you need to do is make sure you don't have any references to it and it will be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you have your indices for the iterators wrong.
If you look closer (or log the variables) you'll see that in the `recur` iterator `i == index` always.

It's iterating 7 times, each time overwriting `answer` with an `ArrayList` that is growing with `index`.

Only the first one printed correctly because you are setting that maxed out `i` as `index` of `recur` where it becomes your starting index, and your ending index is the same size as the input array.

After the first iteration there is nothing to iterate on, so empty array.

If you want to use recursion you need to call the same method from itself and fix your indices.

```java
public static ArrayList<Integer> practice(int start, int end){
    
    ArrayList<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
        answer.add(i)
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
    
    practice(start++, end);
    
}
```